# Canada to Mexico via USA: Do I need and ESTA or visa?

Tags: transit

I have UK Passport and am Canadian Citizen. Flying to Mexico via Dallas. Do I need an ESTA or Visa?

Comment: Do you have a Canadian Passport?

Answer (score 1):

Everybody needs to be able to enter the US to transit there. This means that as a UK citizen, you generally need an ESTA for your transit in Dallas. If you would fly to Mexico directly, you would not need an ESTA but could still use the Visa Waiver Program (i.e. you do not necessarily need a visa).

But because travelling to Mexico does not extend or reset the 90-day period of entry, the clock would start when you transit in Dallas and the whole Mexico-US part of the trip must be shorter than that. See [CBP FAQ about the VWP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/194/~/visa-waiver-program---eligible-countries) for more on this. If you are staying longer than that in total, a visa would then be required for your stay in the US.

But all that is mostly relevant if you only have your UK passport with you and can't prove that you are also a Canadian citizen. [There are other rules for Canadian citizens](http://canada.usembassy.gov/visas.html) (and in some arcane details, for Canadian residents but that's probably not relevant here). If you have a Canadian passport or, if entering by land, another document compliant with the [Western Travel Hemisphere Initiative](http://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/whti_state_factsheet.pdf), it would seem easier to use that.

Comment: The WTHI and the document to which you linked concern land and sea travel.  For air travel, a passport is required.  You might be able to get away with a UK passport along with proof of Canadian citizenship in lieu of ESTA, but I wouldn't risk it if I were you (or rather if I were the OP).

Comment: @phoog I overlooked that, it's now corrected, thanks.

Comment: You may have been misled by the canada.usembassy.gov page to which you link.  It says (confusingly at best; incorrectly at worst) "To enter the United States by air, land or sea, Canadian visitors must have a document that complies with the Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative."